# Passing column name and data frame to custom function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, sapply, mapply

I am trying to write a function in R that:

1) Receives a data frame and column name as parameters.
2) Performs an operation on the column in the data frame.

```
func <- function(col, df)
{
  col = deparse(substitute(col))
  print(paste("Levels: ", levels(df[[col]])))
}


func(Col1, DF)

func(Col2, DF)

mapply(func, colnames(DF)[1:2], DF)
```

Output

```
> func(Col1, DF)
[1] "Levels:  GREEN"  "Levels:  YELLOW"

> func(Col2, DF)
[1] "Levels:  0.1" "Levels:  1"  

> mapply(func, colnames(DF)[1:2], DF)
 Error in `[[.default`(df, col) : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Can you show your `DF` as a small reproducible example

Answer (score 1):

Two things :

- in your function `func`, you apply `deparse(substitute(col))` to an object `col` you expected is not a string. So it works with `func(Col1, DF)`. But in your `mapply()` call, your argument `colnames(...)` is a string, so it create an error. Same error obtained with `func('Col1', DF)`.
- in a `mapply()` call, all arguments need to be a vector or a list. So you need to use `list(df, df)`, or if you don't want to replicate, remove the argument `df` of your function `func`.

This is one alternative that should work:

```
func <- function(col, df)
{
  print(paste("Levels: ", levels(df[,col])))
}

mapply(FUN = func, colnames(DF)[1:2], list(DF, DF))
```

Comment: Thank you @demarsylvain.

I did try the code you suggested and it doesn't run, unfortunately. The output I get is:

Error in mapply(FUN = func, colnames(df)[1:2], list(df, df)) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Comment: `mapply(FUN = func, c('Species', 'Species'), list(iris, iris))` runs without error.
Can we have a sample of your dataset ?

Comment: `> func <- function(col)
+ {
+   print(paste("Levels: ", levels(df[,col])))
+ }
> mapply(FUN = func, c('Species', 'Species'), list(iris, iris))
Error in (function (col)  : unused argument (dots[[2]][[1]])`

Comment: as you remove the argument `df` in your function, your `mapply()` call is not correct. This call use the dataframe `df`, and probably there is no column named *Species* in this dataframe. You can remove this argument only if you always work on the same dataset. If you change (like in this example with `iris`), you need the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the last comment of @demarsylvain - maybe a copy-paste error on your side, you should have done:

```
func <- function(col,df) {
  print(paste("Levels: ", levels(df[,col])))
}

mapply(FUN = func, c('Species', 'Species'), list(iris, iris))
```

you did:

```
func <- function(col) {
  print(paste("Levels: ", levels(df[,col])))
}

mapply(FUN = func, c('Species', 'Species'), list(iris, iris))
```

Please upvote and accept the solution of @demarsylvain, it works

EDIT to adress your comment:

To have a generic version for an arbitrary list of column names you can use this code, sorry for the loop :)

```
func <- function(col,df) {
  print(paste("Levels: ", levels(df[,col])))
}

cnames = colnames(iris)


i <- 1
l = list()
while(i <= length(cnames)) {
  l[[i]] <- iris
  i <- i + 1
}

mapply(FUN = func, cnames, l)
```

Comment: Thank you! If my data frame has 1000 columns and I wanted to do mapply, would it be possible?